Best way to create multiple buttons with proper padding and alignment
I am creating quiz-like application. My aim is to open each question from separate button (box). The number of buttons is not constant, so I generate them dynamically.
However I have a problem to unify their size (each should have same width and height) and set spaces between them and screen.
I would like to achieve something similar to this, but as you can see, width of the buttons varies and it is differently padded to each side of the screen.

So buttons should be organized like this:
[dynamic space to edge][button][button space][button][buttons space][.....][button][dynamic space to edge].
I've tried like this:
Widget getSectionBoxes(String id, num j) {
  List<Widget> boxes = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < questions[id].length; i++) {
    j++;
    String questionId = questions[id][i];
    
    boxes.add(OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          debugPrint(questionId);
        },
        style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ))),
        child: Text(j.toString())));
        boxes.add(const SizedBox(width: 10));
  }

  return Wrap(
    alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
    children: boxes,
  );
}

I've tried using Wrap widget, which orders boxes the way I want, but then there is no spaces. If I add sizedBox widget (width: 10) between buttons, then I have additional space to left or right edge. It is especially visible in a first row.

@pskink: Using Padding with EdgeInsets.all(10.0), will set space between buttons to 20.0 and space to screen edges to 10.0. With higher values the minimal space to edge will be also bigger. That's a problem for me.

so add the outer padding for Wrap widget with another EdgeInsets.all(10.0) - so it looks like: Padding(10) > Wrap[childern_with_padding(10)]

In that case I will have
[edge of the screen | 10 padding | Wrap | 10 padding | edge of screen] and inside Wrap [10 padding | buttons | 10 padding]
I want specified padding just between buttons but not to the edges of the screen.

i thought that you want 20 pixels between buttons and at least 20 pixels on the edges... so now i dont know what is your real intent

I want to things
First: 20 pixels between buttons
Second: space to the edges is not fixed - it can be anything from 0 up to size of button (if there is a bigger space, then additional button would fit instead).

Try below code hope its help to you, I have used padLeft method for single digit ID
declaration:
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonList = [];
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
      jsonList.add({"Id": i});
    }

UI:
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
    child: Wrap(
      spacing: 10.0,
      runSpacing: 10.0,
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      children: List.generate(
        jsonList.length,
        (index) => OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(
            jsonList[index]['Id'].toString().padLeft(2, "0"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),

Result Screen- 

This looks fine, the issue is that, I can't use padLeft. I don't want additional zeroes, and depending on the page I may have different number of questions (from singular ones to hundreds).

You can use staggered grid view to get this result
Builder(builder: (context) {
    var noOfItem = 50;
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    int itemsIn1Row =
        (screenWidth / 101).floor(); //to get the max no of items in row
    var paddingWidth = (screenWidth - itemsIn1Row * 101) / 2;
    return AlignedGridView.extent(
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: noOfItem,
      maxCrossAxisExtent: 100, //or whatever you want to pass
      mainAxisSpacing: 20,
      crossAxisSpacing: 20,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: paddingWidth),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: Center(
            child: Text((index + 1).toString()),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


